# Loop through all columns and add all possible combinations in regression model - Python

Tags: python

I want to write a function where when we pass a dataframe with A, B, C and Y columns, the function would return a model with all possible combinations of A,B,C along with the interaction terms.

The output I would want is the output of ,

```
smf.ols('Y~ A + B + C + A*B + B*C + C*A + A*B*C' , data = dataframe).fit()
```

Initially I have tried,

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column])
```

But I am not sure how to proceed after this.This may be pretty open. But anybody can give an idea, I can try and form it. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with the domain you're working on but if you want all combinations of `A`, `B` and `C` taking atleast two at a time, you can get them like so

```
import itertools

itertools.chain(itertools.combinations(['A','B','C'], 2), itertools.combinations(['A', 'B', 'C,'], 1))
```

You can then massage this into the expression that you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I have tried this, a= it.chain(it.combinations(df.columns,2), it.combinations(df.columns,1)). But not able to see the output. Getting <itertools.chain at 0x91b1b50>. Can you tell me how to access this?

Comment: You can iterate through it using `for i in` or if you just want to debug and check it out, pass that as an argument to `list`.